# Regular expression - split by period (except St.)

Tags: python, regex

I am reading lines, one by one in Python. I have to split the lines if they contain end of a sentence. I am using re.split functionality:

```
words= re.split(r'[.!?]', line)
```

This works well except when I encounter abbreviations such as 'St.'. Is there a way to split by '.!?' but ignore when it is used as 'St.'?

Comment: Did you try negative lookbehind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using a negative lookbehind:

```
words = re.split(r'(?<!St)[.!?]', line)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5QAgPp/1)